# Multiple URL parameter Rewrite rule doesn't work

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i'm trying to make the URL write rule work but it doesn't show any data after the rule is applied.

**The URL** (without rewrite)

```
http://example.com/categories.php?explore=design&sc=css
```

**The URL** (with rewrite)

```
http://example.com/design/css/
```

**The Rewrite Rule i have**

```
#Level-1
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /categories\.php\?explore=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ categories/%1/? [R=302,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^categories/([^/]+)/?$ categories.php?explore=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

#Level-2
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /categories\.php\?explore=([^\s&]+)&sc=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ categories/%1/%2/? [R=302,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^categories/([^/]+)/?$ categories.php?explore=$1&sp=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

The above does work for only 1 Level, Whats wrong with the 2nd Level?

Comment: Have your tried moving level2 to first place ?

Comment: @PedroLobito yeah, i did but no results....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /categories\.php\?explore=([^\s&]+)&sc=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ categories/%1/%2/ [R=302,L,NE]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /categories\.php\?explore=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ categories/%1/ [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^categories/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ categories.php?explore=$1&sc=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^categories/([^/]+)/?$ categories.php?explore=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

(and you wrote `sp` with the first and `sc` with the last...)